# Logstash cannot connect to Elasticsearch when using Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I am using Elastic search a Logstash for logging for a Django application in docker containers. The logs are sent to the Logstash, but it fails to forward them to Elasticsearch. It shows these errors:

```
[2023-04-26T11:48:07,870][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Failed to perform request {:message=>"Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.6] failed: Connection refused", :exception=>Manticore::SocketException, :cause=>#<Java::OrgApacheHttpConn::HttpHostConnectException: Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.6] failed: Connection refused>}
[2023-04-26T11:48:07,870][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::SocketException] Connect to elasticsearch:9200 [elasticsearch/172.25.0.6] failed: Connection refused"}
```

This is the docker-compose file (it does not contain volumes part and other containers that are not relevant). The docker-compose contains a docker network git-reverse-proxy. The settings work on my local dev environment so there might be a problem with the network configuration, but I was unable to configure the network to remove the error.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.7.0
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
      - 5959:5959
    volumes:
      - logs_volume:/logs:ro
      - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    networks:
      - git-reverse-proxy

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.0
    hostname: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_volume:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - git-reverse-proxy

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.7.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - git-reverse-proxy

networks:
  git-reverse-proxy:
    external: true
```

And this is the `logstash.conf` file:

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5959
        codec => json
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "amcr"
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks good with one missing config. I believe the elasticsearch is not working because of the bootstrap check.
Add       - `discovery.type=single-node` under the environment.
Here is an example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.8
    container_name: elasticsearch-ui
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.17.8
    container_name: kibana-ui
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```